# Can't run any commands in zsh: "Command not found"

Tags: windows, bash, shell, terminal, zsh

I am simply trying to set up a dev environment to code on my Windows 10 PC for use alongside my Mac when I need it.

I have installed Bash, Z shell and Node.js.

All I want to do, bare minimum, is simply:

1. Be able to run npm commands, etc. (`npm install X`)
2. Open files with appropriate programs from the terminal. (on Mac, I can run `open index.html` or `atom .`)

**My problem:** Literally no commands work. I can't run `node -v`, I can't do `start index.html`, I can't even open the current directory I'm in with `explorer`.

For every command, I receive an error: `zsh: Command not found (:node/start/explorer/etc.)`

I am guessing it has something to do with my PATH variables? I'm not sure; I'm relatively new...

Please help - I've spent four hours searching Google, Stack Overflow, page after page, but somehow can't find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the `$PATH` content. `echo "$PATH"`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an 'eco-system challenge'... :)

Perhaps whatever tool you used to install the tools you mention:

- did not do a complete install OR
- requires a 'reboot' to enable all the goodies?

I suggest using a small footprint Linux OS in a VM for this type of tinkering; there are many challenges in using *nix tools on Windows - better to learn/experiment in a more Bash-friendly environment, and then, when comfy, bring the tool sets to another OS.

If you still want to give things a whirl:

- locate your Bash binary
- Right-click and select 'run as admin'
- then use your favorite online Bash tutorial or book to explore...

:)
Dale